# Multiple user profiles

Tags: android, profiles

I experienced something weird on my Android tablet. It had been turned off for several weeks and then when I turned it on, it rebooted. Previously, it was just in sleep (standby) mode. But after rebooting, I noticed that the entire device was reset to its factory defaults. All my apps were gone and everything wiped.

Then a few days later I rebooted the device and was surprised to see that all my apps were back again and everything restored as it was. I don't use any backup/restore software, so I am really curious to know how this could happen? Does Android support multiple user profiles? If multiple boot profiles is supported, can this be utilized by an app through some API?

Comment: No multi users / boot profiles supported by default. But maybe the boot with no apps was borked and could not access internal storage (and apps) which would mean data was actually not reset to default but simply unreachable.

Comment: I thought Linux in general supports multiple profiles. Are you saying Google stripped this out of their version?

Comment: It's not stripped but used in a different way: each app is a unique user (> per app permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not currently support multiple (simultaneous) user profiles.  If you do want to achieve this, there is [an app that supports it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme&hl=en) (perhaps more than one), but it involves having a rooted device.

I have personally used this on my home tablet, and it works quite nicely, but requires a reboot to access the other profiles.